# Google play store updates not getting received after I update my app

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play

I recently updated my app in Google play store, I just went in to increment the **versioncode** and added the new apk however my mobile has not received the updates for the new published app.

It's been 1 day, the update is launched. I just added some permission for my app like I added GCM feature to the app, does it for this issue, my mobile is not getting notification for the update.

Comment: Your device will only receive the update if you're application is signed with the same production keystore. You can check if that's the case by going to Google Play and attempting to perform the update yourself. It's likely that you're running a version with a different keystore.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma I have created the key store using following procedure given in the below URL
http://www.instructables.com/id/Publishing-an-Android-App-to-the-Google-Play-Store/?ALLSTEPS 

After then I always sign the app(export apk) using the same key. Is it not right?

Comment: I just tried checking the jarsigner to check if they are signed with same keystore and I found that all apks are signed with same keystore.

I used the below command in terminal

jarsigner -verify -verbose -keystore keystore_file apk_file.apk